# How to print a payload text from resultset in java

Tags: java

I have sql queried for the particular data using jdbc in java.

Now I have payload text in the result set. Anyone please help how to read the payload text from resultset in JAVA. Below is my code giving exception

`System.out.println(set.getString(columnumber));`

I have payload text like below,

`<tag1>Data1</tag1>
<tag2>Data2</tag2>
<tag3>Data3</tag3>`

My issue is that the payload have 'lines' as mentioned above that cannot print using,

`System.out.println(set.getString(columnumber));`

Please help me to print the payload text from resultset in JAVA.

Comment: You have a capital O in your code. Use ``System.out.println(set.getString(columnumber));``. If that doesnt work, please show us the error.

Comment: It's not due to the syntaxt, I manually written the post and so I typed wrongly. Issue is payload having lines but we cannot read using 'getString'. I need a way to read a payload text from resultset.

Comment: What is the database you are using? Are you saying that only the first line of your payload (`<tag1>Data1</tag1>`) gets printed?

Comment: okay, again: show us the error. "Below is my code giving exception" is not enough, we cannot magically guess what is happening.

Comment: Connection conn = DBconnection.getConnection();
  Statement st = conn.createStatement();
  ResultSet set = st.executeQuery(query);
set.next();
for(int j=0;j<meta.getColumnCount();j++){

     System.out.println(set.getString(j+1));
}
The above code I am using is printing all the column values but when comes to the Payload column, it prints null and throwing below exception,

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.rad.finsynch.ControllerMain.getTransType(ControllerMain.java:99)

Comment: But I am sure that the payload column have got value and checked in DB also.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this issue. If the database column is payload text, to get it as a string in the resultset, added the below function in the SQL query

```
columnname.getCLOBVal()
```

This returns the payload text as string and I can able to print it in Java by using

```
System.out.println(set.getString(columnumber));
```

Thanks everyone for your valuable time to suggest idea on this.